# Regext help for decimal numbers

Tags: regex

I have regex which should check if string is decimal number...

```
^([\+\-])?\d{1,10}[\.,]?\d{1,10}?$
```

1. start with single + or - //**not mandatory**
2. follow with digit
3. follow with decimal single separator //**not mandatory**
4. and follow with one to ten digits //**not mandatory** -- *this should be follow only in case of decimal separator*

but is not working in case of

```
-1 //single digit
```

and if there are more than `10 digits w/o decimal separator -> should fail`

```
  assertEquals(false,  Util.isDecimalNumber("12345678901"));
```

Is there a easier way to check if string is a decimal number?

Comment: Are you limited to regex? Nearly every programming language provides a function that does this for you.

Comment: The problem is in the end of your RegExp. You need to use `{0` quantifier instead of `?`: **`^([\+\-])?\d{1,10}[\.,]?\d{0,10}$`**

Comment: Is the number `123456.789123456` valid?

Comment: Not correct than number can be finished with decimal separator like"1."

decimal separator is not mandatory but if string contains it after it should be a number again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[\+\-]?\d{1,10}([\.,]\d{1,10})?$
```

Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/80

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect syntax in the fractional part of your RegExp.

Instead of

```
^([\+\-])?\d{1,10}[\.,]?\d{1,10}?$
```

It should be either

```
^([\+\-])?\d{1,10}([\.,]\d{1,10})?$
```

or

```
^([\+\-])?\d{1,10}[\.,]?\d{0,10}$
```

The first one is more suitable, because it disallows decimal point without fractional part like `123.`.

In words, it will become:

1. start with single + or - //not mandatory.
2. follow with digit
3. follow with decimal single separator **and** follow with the one to ten digits //not mandatory

Check [this Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD3kP8/1) out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

```
^[-+]?\d{1,10}(?:[.,]\d{1,10})?$
```

Comment: decimal,

in some countries coma is decimal separator and in other dot.

No thousands' separators ;)

Comment: @J.Doe So, if the input has a decimal separator; it can exceed the 10 digit limit?

Comment: ^[-+]?\d{1,10}(?:[\.,][1-9]\d{0,9})?$

thx for hint - that it seems to be OK.

Comment: @J.Doe When you use a character set, you do not need to escape the `.`. So, `[.,]` is same as `[\.,]`.

Comment: Yes it can longer i.e. 1234567890.1234567890 is a max size. And thx for an advice.

Comment: And this is correct working solution for me and none from above - you should get vote up!

Comment: @J.Doe There can be only one answer on a question.